# При переходе на "назад" в браузере отображается json ответ который получался через ajax

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Словил интересную багу у себя, но понятия не имею как ее пофиксить, может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.
По шагам.

1. Элемент списка
2. Переходим на страницу 2 https://clipstips.ru/blog?page=2
3. Перходим на страницу 1 через пагинацию
4. Нажимаем на кнопку под списокм статей «Показать еще»
5. Нажимаем на кнопку назад в браузере и получаем вот такую страницу http://prntscr.com/o4exnq

Comment: Не нужно использовать одинаковый роутинг для html и json. Хотя бы http-глагол на POST поменяйте или Accept без text/html,.. а лучше сделайте роут /blog.json

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, при ответе на ajax запрос добавляют заголовки

```
[
'Cache-Control' => 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
'Pragma' => 'no-cache'
]
```

Проблема решена.